# SQL Simple Query - Multiple entries filtering

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Newbie SQL Query question: 
I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

I have a table:

```
<name>  <color>
steve    red
mark     red
steve    green
john     red
ryan     red
```

What I would like to do is have the results only display the names that contain RED in the color column.
    The results would be:

```
     mark
     john
     ryan
```

Since steve has a color green as well, it would not show up.

Anyone out there knows?

EDIT:
THANK YOU FOR THE ANSWERS.  I do see that I should have said "red and no other color" in the results.  Sorry for the confusion but thank you for the super speedy replies!

Comment: What did you try ? This would in the first pages of any book/tutorial/lesson on SQL for beginners.

Comment: Not necessarily - I don't think this can be solved without a subquery or a join.

Comment: How can you say this without knowing anything of his database ? For all we know both fields are in the same table which makes it a simple `SELECT ... WHERE` query.

Comment: Nevermind that. You're right. The wording confused me.

Comment: Sorry :( First question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just query with a `WHERE` clause and a `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
WHERE color = 'red'
   AND name NOT IN (
                    SELECT name
                    FROM yourTable
                    WHERE color <> 'red'
                )
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b78/1)

Or you can use `WHERE` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE color = 'red'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT  t2.name
                    FROM yourTable t2
                    WHERE  t2.color <> 'red'
                     AND t1.name = t2.name
                )
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b78/4)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, here is a solution using windowing functions:

```
select *
from (
  select name, 
         color, 
         count(distinct color) over (partition by name) as color_cnt
  from the_table
) t
where color = 'red' 
and color_cnt = 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d267e/3

There is a slight change that this *might* be faster than the solutions with a sub-select because most probably only a single scan over the table will be needed (although possibly the other solutions could use an index on the color column which could make the two scans cheaper than the single scan)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the different POV :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
WHERE color = 'red'
and name not in (
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
WHERE color != 'red')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM mytable
WHERE color = 'red'
AND name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM mytable
    WHERE color <> 'red'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it [Everyone has a fiddle for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cee24/8)

```
select t.name from t
join 
   (select name,count(1) cnt from t
     group by name
      having count(1) = 1) n
      on t.name = n.name
```

Comment: Doesn't work (returns `steve` which is not desired).  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d699a/3

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <name> 
FROM <table> 
WHERE <color> = 'red'
AND <name> NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT <name> 
                     FROM <table> 
                     WHERE <color> != 'red')
```

Comment: This will return Steve, which is a result I don't want.

Comment: `Since steve has a color green as well, it would not show up.`  Not worded extremely well, but it's there...

Comment: The bad wording made me think the OP had a non-working query and meant something else with that phrase, but I gues you're right...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but thanks for the reply.  I didn't downvote, btw.  I don't even think I can.